# What is the purpose of double slash in zfs-auto-snapshot's cron job?

Tags: cron, sh, zfs

I had recently set up *zfs-auto-snapshot* on a machine to take snapshots regularly. This tool does it's thing by creating the following cron job files:

```
/etc/cron.daily/zfs-auto-snapshot
/etc/cron.hourly/zfs-auto-snapshot
/etc/cron.d/zfs-auto-snapshot
/etc/cron.weekly/zfs-auto-snapshot
/etc/cron.monthly/zfs-auto-snapshot
```

All of them have more or less the same kind of code:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Only call zfs-auto-snapshot if it's available
which zfs-auto-snapshot > /dev/null || exit 0

exec zfs-auto-snapshot --quiet --syslog --label=60 --keep=24  //
```

Now, do the last two forward slashes ( **//** ) have any particular purpose?

What I *really* want to do is add my own command in the end of the line, if and when **zfs-auto-snapshot** has completed its task (`&& sh script.sh`), and I wonder if it would be more appropriate to do so before or after the slashes?

Comment: /bin/sh is usually not bash

Comment: You're right, thanks. I've edited my tags. Also tried a bit and it seems like I must add other script after the //, otherwise I get an error, which makes sense, as // is, after all, part of the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [man-page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/zfs-auto-snapshot/zfs-auto-snapshot.8.en.html) `//` is a shortcut for all datasets. So it's significant.

```
zfs-auto-snapshot [ options] [-l label] <'//' | name [ name...]>
...
name: Filesystem and volume names, or '//' for all ZFS datasets.
```